# -Laravel 5.2 insert logged in users foreign key automatically into product table when creating product

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

i've been working on a CRUD system lately, what i want is that when a logged in user creates a product on my website his name will automatically be inserted as a foreign key into my product table.

this is my Product model i've made for it.

```
//inkoopprijs = sell price
//verkoop prijs = buy price
//naam = product name


protected $fillable = ['naam', 'inkoopprijs', 'verkoopprijs','users_id','created_at', 'updated_at'];

protected $table = "product";
```

this is my ProductController store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{  
   $product = Product::create($request->only(['naam', 'inkoopprijs', 'verkoopprijs', 'users_id']));

   return redirect(route('product.index'));  
}
```

Comment: But you already have the `users_id`, so you can just get the username already?

Comment: what i mean is that when im logged in as for example "test" with the id of 1 that the id automaticly gets inserted into the product table when creating a product @jerodev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current logged in user with `Auth::user();` or `auth()->user();`

We can also access the identifier with `Auth::id();`

```
Product::create([
    'naam' => $request->get('naam'),
    'inkoopprijs' => $request->get('inkoopprijs'),
    'verkoopprijs' => $request->get('verkoopprijs'),
    'users_id' => \Auth::id()
]);
```

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: thank you very much for this, its works perfectly how i want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events) like so:

```
Product::creating(function ($product) {
    $user = auth()->user();
    $product->users_id = $user->id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use users id as hidden field in the form but need to consider the security aspects of using users id in the form. It depends on where you are using. May be you can use this method is the user is already authenticated.

```
<input type="hidden" name="users_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
```